# MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 Keeps Asking for Accessibility Permission for an App When Launched from XCode 13.2.1 Even After Granting the Permission

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility, macos-monterey

When I launch an app from Xcode in order to debug, it keeps asking accessibility permission even after granting it.

If I archive, run from finder, and grant accessibility, it works fine.

I also tried removing the app from security & privacy.

It used to work fine in MacOS 11, but it doesn't seem to work with MacOS 12.2.1, Xcode 13.2.1.

I'd appreciate any tip.

Comment: Sounds like something to report to Apple. Unclear how this would be a programming problem suitable to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a actual bug. Apple annoyingly and often changes how to deal with this kind of things, so Stackoverflow has many questions related to how to do things on Xcode, not necessary coding.

Comment: The trouble is that no one else has this problem, and you have not explained how to have it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814854/how-to-prompt-for-accessibility-features-in-a-macos-app-from-the-appdelegate Related?

Comment: matt, I do have this problem. I am developing a screen grabbing macos app and as soon as I change a single line of code, my Monterey System Preferences prompts me to grant access. Once in the panel, the app is already listed and enabled from last time. To fix it, one has to remove the row and start over which is super annoying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist accessibility permissions between builds in xcode 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312351/persist-accessibility-permissions-between-builds-in-xcode-13)

Comment: @soundflix solved the problem for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you can't have duplicate versions of same app stored on your machine. Once I deleted all the debug builds as well as the release in /Applications folder, it worked.

Maybe you can allow only one file with same app name.